# Angular-ui nested views in HTML5 mode get 404 not fount for template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

I have a problem with my app in HTML5 mode and nested URL, let me explain.

This is an example routing file:

```
angular.module('widgets').config(['$stateProvider', 
    function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.
        state('widgets', {
            url: '/widgets',
            abstract: true
        }).
        state('widgets.create', {
            url: '/create',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'modules/widgets/views/widgets.create.client.view.html',
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

This works until I keep HTML5 mode off with:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

As I turn on the HTML5 mode with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

It happens that as soon as I try the nested URL `/widgets/create` I get 404 error not found for the templateUrl file because it prefix it with `/widgets/`so instead getting this:

> http://127.0.0.1/modules/widgets/views/widgets.create.client.view.html <-- 200 OK HTML5 OFF

It instead try to get:

> http://127.0.0.1/**widgets**/modules/widgets/views/widgets.create.client.view.html <-- 404 Not Found HTML5 ON

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found it! When you enable `HTML5mode` you need to add this tag in the `head` of your main document:

```
<head>
   <base href="/" />
   ...
</head>
```

Here is the explanation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-assets-and-templates-are-not-loading